# MySQL select rows between a given interval

Tags: php, mysql, sql

table videos

```
id | title  | time
------------------------
1  | o'najr | 1406332800
```

I want to select rows which are between the interval of 6 months from a given time. Both newer or older

So if the query time is for ex. 1446076800 all the rows which 6 months older or 6 months newer than this will be selected.

`time` is in the `UNIX TIMESTAMP` format.

So if a video is uploaded on October 2015 all the videos which are uploaded on April 2015 and newer will be selected. Also all the videos from October 2015 up to April 2016 will be selected.

`6 months <---- || query time || ----> 6 months`

This is my query but it doesn't work at all. It just as a structure not a working query.

`:time` is the variable which will be used for the query.

```
select `title` 
from `videos` 
where DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time - :time)) > INTERVAL 6 MONTH 
      or 
      DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(:time - time)) < INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

Comment: Why did you tag it with `php`?

Comment: Look at the `BETWEEN` syntax i.e. `WHERE x BETWEEN y and z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't quite make sense. You're trying to compare a specific date to a time interval.

Try this:

```
SELECT title FROM videos 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(time) BETWEEN
    DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(:time), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
    AND DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(:time), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Comment: Good. Maybe it is even nicer using `BETWEEN`? And I think you need to call `FROM_UNIXTIME` also on `time`

Comment: Good suggestions. I will fix it.

Comment: Also, `DATE_FORMAT` is unnecessary when using `FROM_UNIXTIME`.

Comment: Bear in mind that your `BETWEEN` version gives different results, as `BETWEEN` is inclusive.